# Programatically attach a field to a content type

Tags: nodes

I am in the situation where I need to made some modifications to a content type in my .install file. I know how to create a content type programmatically, just create it via the UI and export, and recreate the form to submit it.

In this case deleting the existing content type and recreating it screws up the existing content type instances, so I need to add an existing field to an existing content type. Is that easy to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Anything in the UI eventually has to call a function, so...

The UI for editing a content type goes to path:

```
admin/content/node-type/NODETYPE
```

This path is "owned" by the cck module.  Looking in there, you can dig through the forms and hook_menu()s etc to see it eventually calls a function:

```
content_field_instance_create($field)
```

which is defined in

```
content.crud.inc
```

inside the cck module's inc directory.